# Edit records CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm developing a basic crud application using **PHP Codeigniter 3 with MySQL database**.
I have done add and list method successfully but now I want to edit the record and have included an edit button in the records table in view. when I click on the button it will go to my edit record view but it shows some errors. I checked everything but I fail to resolve it.

**This is my controller**

```
<?php

class User extends CI_controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('User_model');

        $users = $this->User_model->getUsers();
        // print_r($users);
        $data = array();
        $data['users'] = $users;

        $this->load->view('users/list',$data);
    }

    public function create()
    {

        //load model here

        $this->load->model('User_model');



        //load library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('ckeditor');
        $this->load->library('ckfinder');

        //set rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('projectname', 'Projectname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('projecttype', 'Projecttype', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('projectdescription', 'Projectdescription', 'required');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('termname', 'Termname', 'required');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('termdescription', 'Termdescription', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('article_description', 'Article_description', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

            // print_r($_POST);
            // Array ( [name] => muhammad zawish [projectname] => test [projecttype] => Hardware [phone] => 03206270391 [email] => muhammadzawish@gmail.com [address] => Gondal Road, Sialkot, Punjab, Pakistan [projectdescription] => aaaaaaaaaa [termname] => aaaaaa [termdescription] => aaaaaaaa )

            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $projectname = $this->input->post('projectname');
            $projecttype = $this->input->post('projecttype');
            $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $address = $this->input->post('address');
            $projectdescription = $this->input->post('projectdescription');
            // $termname = $this->input->post('termname');
            // $termdescription = $this->input->post('termdescription');
            $article_description = $this->input->post('article_description');

            // $formData = array('name' => $name, 'projectname' => $projectname, 'projecttype' => $projecttype, 'phone' => $phone, 'email' => $email, 'address' => $address, 'projectdescription' => $projectdescription, 'termname' => $termname, 'termdescription' => $termdescription,);

            $formData = array('name' => $name, 'projectname' => $projectname, 'projecttype' => $projecttype, 'phone' => $phone, 'email' => $email, 'address' => $address, 'projectdescription' => $projectdescription, 'article_description' => $article_description);

            //ck editor files 

            $this->ckeditor->basePath = base_url() . 'asset/ckeditor/';
            $this->ckeditor->config['toolbar'] = array(
                array('Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList')
            );
            $this->ckeditor->config['language'] = 'it';
            $this->ckeditor->config['width'] = '730px';
            $this->ckeditor->config['height'] = '300px';

            //Add Ckfinder to Ckeditor
            $this->ckfinder->SetupCKEditor($this->ckeditor, '../../asset/ckfinder/');

            $this->User_model->add_user($formData);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record has been added successfully');
            redirect(base_url('user/index'));

        } else {

            $this->load->view('users/create');
        }
    }

    function edit($id){

        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $row = $this->User_model->getUser($id);
        $data1 = array();
        $data1['row'] = $row; 
        $this->load->view('users/edit', $data1);

    }
}
```

**this is my model**

```
<?php
    class User_model extends CI_Model{
           
           public function add_user($formArray){

            // $this->load->library('session');
            $this->db->insert('users', $formArray);
        }

        //for view data fetch from database

        public function getUsers(){
           $users = $this->db->get('users')->result_array();
           return $users;
        }

        //for edit record
        function getUser($id){

            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $row = $this->db->get('users')->row_array();            
            return $row;
        }   

    }
?>
```

**when I access my edit.php view**

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Comment: I didn't code in it. it's empty. and it should show empty page but it cant

Comment: how you trying to access edit.php ?

Comment: hello, thanks a lot. I tried again and check the code there is some issue with the link. I resolve it and its works successfully.